# requestLocationUpdates de LocationManager

Tags: android

tengo una duda, espero puedan ayudarme.

Estoy usando el método requestLocationUpdates que te regresa datos tomados por GPS cada cierto tiempo. Mi objetivo es que estos datos se envíen a un servidor, aún cuando la aplicación esté cerrada.

Tengo la idea que si lo envío en el onCreate de la aplicación no tendría problemas con sobrecargar el hilo principal, ya que esto se ejecutaría sólo una vez, pero no sé cual sería el tiempo de vida del método.

¿Cuál es la buena práctica en este tipo de desarrollos?

Les dejo mi código en onCreate, haciendo pruebas en el emulador esto funciona (no se bien que tan eficientemente con respecto a la memoria), pero sólo mientras la aplicación se encuentre activa o en la lista de aplicaciones usadas ultimamente, al sacarlo de esa lista deja de funcionar hasta volver a levantar la aplicación.

```
public class PacienteApp extends Application {
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    try {
        LocationManager locManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Location loc = locManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if (loc != null) {
            Log.i("location", String.valueOf(loc.getLongitude()));
            Log.i("location", String.valueOf(loc.getLatitude()));
        }
        LocationListener locListener = new LocationListener() {
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                Log.i("location", String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));
                Log.i("location", String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
            }

            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                Log.i("info", "Provider OFF");
            }

            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                Log.i("info", "Provider ON");
            }

            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
                Log.i("LocAndroid", "Provider Status: " + status);
                Log.i("info", "Provider Status: " + status);
            }
        };
        locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 30000, 500, locListener);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e("ERROR", "Error: " + e);
    }
    finally {
        Log.i("INFO", "Salimos de onCreate");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Hola manduinca, Bienvenido a SO en español, puedes mostrar tu codigo actual, asi es mas facil para otros miembros de la comunidad ayudarte a resolver tu problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar un [**Servicio**](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/components/services.html):

http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/run-background-service/create-service.html

> Un servicio es un componente de aplicación que puede realizar
>   operaciones de larga ejecución en segundo plano y no proporciona una
>   interfaz de usuario. Esto le permite manejar las operaciones de larga
>   duración sin afectar su capacidad de respuesta interfaz de usuario.

Te recomiendo este ejemplo:

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html

Dentr de cada ciclo puedes enviar los valores de Latitud, Longitud al servidor.

Comment: Al final he usado el Service, hasta ahora es lo más cerca que he llegado a una solución ideal. Lanzo el Service desde el onCreate de mi aplicación y queda corriendo en segundo plano. Además agregué un Receiver Broadcast para lanzar nuevamente el Service cada vez que se reinicie el dispositivo.